# Is there an alternative to Keyframes when changing Background of DIV?

Tags: css

I have a DIV where I change the background using Webkit Keyframes, and this is working fine, but I would like to be able to set a time for how long the background should stay before it moves on to the next. I have been looking at animation delays, but I cannot see how I can use this in the project. Is there an alternative to Keyframes or am I missing something I could set as a delay in the Keyframes?

*NB! In my project besides CSS, I also use Bootstrap 4 and jQuery.*

My CSS is this:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes changeBckg {
  0% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_1.png"); }
  15% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_2.png"); }
  30% { background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_3.png"); }
  45% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_4.png"); }
  60% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_5.png"); }
  75% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_6.png"); }
  90% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_7.png"); }
  100% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_8.png"); }
}

@keyframes changeBckg {
  0% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_1.png"); }
  15% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_2.png"); }
  30% { background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_3.png"); }
  45% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_4.png"); }
  60% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_5.png"); }
  75% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_6.png"); }
  90% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_7.png"); }
  100% {background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_8.png"); }
}

.BackgroundAninmation {
  -webkit-animation: changeBckg 20s ease infinite;
  animation: changeBckg 20s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="BackgroundAninmation" style="max-width: 700px;">
</div>
```

Comment: You can manipulate the percentages to get whatever timing you want.

Comment: Okay, but how @Wais Kamal? .. am I missing something, I have 8 background images and 100% to do with, this gives me 14,28% per image, or is % a relative number in KeyFrames?

Comment: `0% { x }, 10% { x }, 20% { y }, 40% { y }, 50% { z }, 70% { z }, 80% { x }, 100% { x }` will give you such a delay. So you need to declare the same background more than once and the period in between the two declarations will serve as the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_1.png"); }
15% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_1.png"); }
15% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_2.png"); }
40% {  background-image: url("img/backgroumd_animations/ad_creation_bg_2.png"); }
```

In the above example you have the same `ad_creation_bg_1.png` background at both 0% - 15% range of your animation and `ad_creation_bg_2.png` for 15% - 40% range.

This means your first background will be completely visible in the first 3 seconds of your animation (*from 0% to 15% of 20s*), then the second background will appear immediately, lasting 5 seconds (*from 15% to 40% of 20s*).

Comment: **Forgot to mention**: for a longer transition effect you can place a gap between each of the couple keyframes set. **For example**: `0% { background-image: url("bg1.png") } 15% { background-image: url("bg1.png") } 20% { background-image: url("bg2.png") } 40% { background-image: url("bg2.png") }`.

Comment: Thank you @Alexandru lancu for the explanation, that helped me very much .. I have it working now :-)